# How to Calculate and return a total cart items in Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I've been going back and forth on this code for sometime now and I'm trying to have a totalQty value in the cart object that returns total number of items in the cart and I want to use that value in the views of course right next to the cart icon in the navigation. Here is my code for the user model and routes:

User model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  role: {
    type: String,
    default: 'BASIC'
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  address: {
    type: String
  },
  apartment: {
    type: String
  },
  country: {
    type: String
  },
  state: {
    type: String
  },
  city: {
    type: String
  },
  zip: {
    type: String
  },
  phone: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  resetToken: String,
  resetTokenExpiration: Date,
  cart: {
    items: [
      {
        productId: {
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: 'Product',
          required: true
        },
        quantity: { type: Number, required: true }
      },
    ],
    totalQty: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0
    }
  }
}, { timestamps: true });

userSchema.methods.addToCart = function (product) {
  const cartProductIndex = this.cart.items.findIndex(cp => {
    return cp.productId.toString() === product._id.toString();
  });
  let newQuantity = 1;
  // let newTotalQty = 1;

  const updatedCartItems = [...this.cart.items];

  if (cartProductIndex >= 0) {
    newQuantity = this.cart.items[cartProductIndex].quantity + 1;
    updatedCartItems[cartProductIndex].quantity = newQuantity;

    newTotalQty = this.cart.totalQty + 1;
    updatedTotalQty = newTotalQty;

  } else {
    updatedCartItems.push({
      productId: product._id,
      quantity: newQuantity
    });
  }

  const updatedCart = {
    items: updatedCartItems,
    totalQty: updatedTotalQty

  };
  this.cart = updatedCart;
  return this.save();
};

userSchema.methods.removeFromCart = function (productId) {
  const updatedCartItems = this.cart.items.filter(item => {
    return item.productId.toString() !== productId.toString();
  });
  this.cart.items = updatedCartItems;
  return this.save();
};

userSchema.methods.clearCart = function () {
  this.cart = { items: [] };
  return this.save();
};

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

User routes:

```
exports.getCart = (req, res, next) => {
  // populate req user
  req.user
    .populate('cart.items.productId')
    .execPopulate()
    .then(user => {
      const products = user.cart.items;
      // render cart view
      res.render('shop/cart', {
        path: '/cart',
        pageTitle: 'Cart - Hashing365.com',
        products: products
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
};

exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
  // extract prod ID
  const prodId = req.body.productId;
  // run DB find with prod ID
  Product.findById(prodId)
    .then(product => {
      // return true && add to cart
      return req.user.addToCart(product);
    })
    .then(result => {
      // re-render same page
      res.redirect('back');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error(err);
      error.httpStatusCode = 500;
      return next(error);
    });
};
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with a way to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [Array reducer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). It should look like this

```
cart.totalQty = cart.items.reduce((sum, item)=>{
    return sum + item.quantity;
},0);
```

Comment: Muhammad, I tried this and it didn't work so I tried running the code sample in the console. Found out it only returns the quantity of the last item in the cart.items array

Comment: @Rex Please check now. it was supposed to be `sum + item.quantity` instead of `item.quantity`

Comment: Thanks! I had to figure that out from the documentation before your comment popped up. Now I'm trying to make that returned value available in globally. How would you recommend doing that aside passing it to res.locals?

Comment: app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.session = req.session;
  res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
  res.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken();
  res.locals.currentUser = req.session.user;
  next();
});

Comment: res.locals.session returns [Object Object]
same with res.locals.currentUser

Comment: Got to fix the issue with res.locals. Thanks again Muhammad